# Can you have multiple groupings on a view?

Tags: views

Is there a way to toggle between several different grouping on one view?

I have a view that is a list of nodes and I need to be able to group them by node title or by created date.   Is there a way to do this without having to create two different views?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create multiple view pages in a single View definition and assign each with the same basic paths, but a different last segment eg. Node/%/Group1 & Node/%/Group2.
2. For each view select a menu item in the second column and set the type to menu tab.  Provide the name to display on each tab.
3. Set one of the pages' menu to default menu tab so it will show up first.  set its parent to already exists.

When you enter the path in the URL, you should get the default page displayed with the menu tabs above the view block.

Answer (score 0):

Look at (Format: Unformatted list | Settings ) Settings. You will find Grouping field jump menu with all of your fields. You can choose one and will do the trick.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.